# Integrating more than one Authentication in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

As per one of current requirement I have to integrate more then one authentication in ASP.NET MVC project.

Project should support following authentication:

- Individual User Accounts (Forms Authentication).
- Work ANd School Accounts (Microsoft Azure Active Directory Authentication).

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?